# How can I stay logged in when web scraping with URLSession?

Tags: swift, web-scraping, nsurlsession, urlsession

With my program I try to login and scrape the home page, however after I log in with a post request (in which the response says successful), when I try to get the home page it says my session has timed out.

I've tried using different types of session, modifying minor parts of the code, and Alamofire with no success

```
import Foundation

let session: URLSession = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30 // seconds
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30 // seconds
    return URLSession(configuration: .default)
}()

let url = URL(string: "examplesite.com")!

var request = URLRequest(url: url)

request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: 
"Content-Type")

request.httpMethod = "POST"

let postString = "Email=exampleemail&Password=examplepass"

request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

//log in
session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
  guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 
  // check for fundamental networking error
    print("\(error)")
    return
  }

  if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode 
    != 200 {           // check for http errors
      print("\(httpStatus.statusCode)")
      print("\(response)")
  }

  let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
  print("\(responseString)")

  let urlnext = URL(string: "example.com/HomePage")!
  //get page after loggin in
  session.dataTask(with: urlnext) { datanext, responsenext, errornext in
  guard let datanext = datanext, errornext == nil else {
    print("\(errornext)")
    return
  }

  let stringnext = String(data: datanext, encoding: .utf8)
  //get page html
  print("\(stringnext)")
  }.resume()

  }.resume()

  // Infinitely run the main loop to wait for our request.
  // Only necessary if you are testing in the command line.
RunLoop.main.run()
```

the results are a successful login {\"msg\":\"\",\"valid\":\"1\"}, and the html code of a time out page instead of the home page

Comment: Unfortunately, it depends entirely upon how the site manages authentication. Many sites will include some special token as a hidden field in subsequent forms. Some use cookies (if you make sure to use the same `URLSession` for subsequent requests, you’ll generally capture those, fine). I’d suggest you use your browser’s “view source code” feature and/or other developer features to reverse engineer how it does it. (Or, sometimes, you can use Charles or Wireshark to observe the interaction, including headers.) But we won't be able to diagnose it based upon the information provided here.

Comment: As an aside, many sites explicitly forbid scraping, so you might want to double check their terms of service so you don’t put yourself (or your users) in legal jeopardy. Also, some sites, if you inquire, may provide web service endpoints that will help keep you out of the weeds of the problems that plague scraping entails (i.e., notably, it’s incredibly fragile approach).

Comment: Finally, remember to percent escape the body of your `x-www-form-urlencoded` request. If, for example, the userid or password ever contain reserved characters, your login attempt will fail unless you percent escape.